# Android - How to get JSON format request and response in Robospice/retrofit

Tags: android, json, web-services, retrofit, robospice

I am new to the Robospice/retrofit libraries. I got some samples from the github. https://github.com/octo-online/RoboSpice-samples/tree/release/robospice-sample-retrofit.

**My Understanding:**

The request is "githubRequest" and the response is the "Contributor.List". The webservice is called by getSpiceManager().execute.

**Code Snippet:**

```
    @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            getSpiceManager().execute(githubRequest, "github", DurationInMillis.ONE_MINUTE, new ListContributorRequestListener());
    } 

public final class ListContributorRequestListener implements RequestListener<Contributor.List> {

    @Override
    public void onRequestFailure(SpiceException spiceException) {
        Toast.makeText(SampleSpiceActivity.this, "failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestSuccess(final Contributor.List result) {
        Toast.makeText(SampleSpiceActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateContributors(result);
    }
}
```

**My Question:** I want to check from the app, whether the request/response("githubRequest"/"Contributor.List") correct JSONs are sent to the service. So How can I sysout the JSON request and response. But the request/response are POJO object. But If I want to print the JSON request and response, How can I do that? 
Anybody help me to do this?

Comment: Android Log size is limited, so if you do some big requests you may not be able to see some particular details you may be interested in. Personally I use Charles proxy to get the requests/responses, its quite easy to setup: http://jaanus.com/blog/2012/02/12/debugging-http-on-an-android-phone-or-tablet-with-charles-proxy-for-fun-and-profit/ . Maybe that will work for you as well.

Comment: @Karolina Rusin: I just sent two parameters in the "githubRequest". is it possible to get the JSON request/response when using the Robospice/retrofit library?

Answer (score 11):

To print the response object first change the callback object type to the generic `Object` type via `Callback<Object> cb`. Then in your success callback you can just log the object to print the Json formatted version to the console.

```
@Override
public void success(Object o, Response response) {
    Log.i("Tag", "Login data " + o.toString());
}
```

To print the request object you can use whatever Json library you use (here I'm using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) to serialize the request object to Json and log that to the console.

```
Log.i("Tag", "Login data " + new Gson().toJson(requestObject));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I 'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure Retrofit in order to see JSON request and response in Log.

```
public class RetrofitSpiceService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {

private static final String BASE_URL = "http://your_url_here";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    addRetrofitInterface(SomeService.class);
}

@Override
protected String getServerUrl() {
    return BASE_URL;
}

@Override
protected Builder createRestAdapterBuilder() {

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .create();

    return super.createRestAdapterBuilder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                    // or .setLog(new AndroidLog("Retrofit"))
            .setLog(new RestAdapter.Log() {
                @Override
                public void log(String msg) {
                    String[] blacklist = {"Access-Control", "Cache-Control", "Connection", "Content-Type", "Keep-Alive", "Pragma", "Server", "Vary", "X-Powered-By",
                            "Content-Length", "Set-Cookie", "OkHttp-Selected-Protocol", "OkHttp-Sent-Millis", "OkHttp-Received-Millis"};
                    for (String bString : blacklist) {
                        if (msg.startsWith(bString)) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d("Retrofit", msg);
                }
            });

}
```

}