# How to customize the response body JSON conversion in Retrofit?

Tags: android, android-networking, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to implement a Rest Client and I ran into some trouble when trying to convert the response body to my model Object.

I have the following in my interface:

```
@POST("/users")
void createUser(@Body RegisterUserToken token, Callback<User> callback);
```

My `User` class is basically a POJO with:

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String language;
    // getters and setters...
}
```

And this is how I use the Rest Client:

```
restClient.createUser(token, new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(User user, Response response) {
        // ...problem is here, with the user object
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that the response body is not being converted to a `User` object. I'm pretty sure the problem is that the server is returning:

```
{"user":{"id":13,"username":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","language":"eng"}}
```

Instead of just:

```
{"id":13,"username":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","language":"eng"}
```

Given that I can't really modify the server code, how can I customize Retrofit/GSON to correctly convert this response body to my User object?

Comment: What does the data look like when you print it out?

Comment: I just get an empty User object (all of this Object's fields initialized to their default values).

Comment: Instead of using a User object use a String and print it out. This way you can find out if the problem is on your end or the server end

Comment: If you don't know how to print it out as a string see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24964462/1167780

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to avoid having to manually deal with GSON within the response callback, but I guess I don't really have a choice right? ha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the POJO class like this:

```
public static class User {
    UserData user;
}   

public static class UserData {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String language;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `Map<String,User>` instead of just `User`. To get the actual `User` object, you can then access the `User` object by using the key "user" on the map.

for example:

```
@POST("/users")
void createUser(@Body RegisterUserToken token, Callback<Map<String, User>> callback);
    restClient.createUser(token, new Callback<Map<String, User>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Map<String, User> map, Response response) {
            User user = map.get("user");
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Usually providing a example code helps the ne asking the question to implement faster, your proposed example.

Comment: Hey @hyp3rs0nik it seems like you might be on the right track. Could you provide come example code? Thanks!

Comment: It would be much better to use a `UserResponse` object which had a `User user` field on it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that would work. I don't really like adding metadata to my model objects but naming it UserResponse I guess is a nice way of wrapping the User object without adding this metadata. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GSON fails parsing the object because you are not getting the root (user) object... Here you will find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25505032/761668

Answer (score 0):

You can use Volley library for rest APIs call where you can customize response easily.